# Objective-c RegEx variable names ($1, $2, etc.)

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex, string, variables

I have a Regular Expression in Objective-C and I need to know how to get a certain variable...

I want to find a string that has the letter "a" somewhere in it followed by any number (including zero) of B's, C's, and D's after it and at the first non-B,C,D I want to close my search statement. Then I want to replace the A with an F and add an F to the end of my search-string.

For example: "ZYXABCBBDBCBDEJKS" would search and return: "ZYX**ABCBBDBCBDE**JKS" ... so the string I am now working with is "ABCBBDBCBDE", I want this string to turn into this string "FBCBBDBCBDEF" and then be put back into the original string... so the final returned string will be "ZYX***F***BCBBDBCBDE***F***JKS"

I'm new to RegEx but I gave it a shot with the below objective-c code and it didn't work... I think this is because my variables on the second line of code (at the "withTemplate" part) are wrong... I shouldn't use "$2" or "$1" should I?

code:

```
regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"A(B|C|D)*([^B|C|D])"
                                                          options:0
                                                            error:nil];
modifiedString = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:myString
                                                         options:0
                                                           range:NSMakeRange(0, [htmlstring length])
                                                    withTemplate:@"F$1$2F"];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your regex - `(B|C|D)*` will only capture the last matched character out of `(B|C|D)`, since `*` is out of the captured group. Also, in a character class, you don't need to use a `pipe` to alternate, as you did in 3rd part. So, either you use `character class`, or you use `pipe` to alternate in groups. And in this particular case, I would suggest to use character class in both place.

So, you can try changing your regex to:

```
"A([BCD]*)([^BCD])"
```

Comment: Trying it now :) Thankyou for your feedback!

Comment: Well, correcting the search expression to what you put made the code work properly to the point where $2 now represented the final character that wasn't a  B,C,D ... however I can't seem to get $1 to represent the multiple B,C,D's that follow the A... So "ABCBDE" becomes "FEF" instead of "FBCBDEF"

Comment: Wait, I left out the "$1" I just realized... standby.

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw.. Yeah it is. It's quite fun, when you get things done so easily. You're welcome :)

Comment: Haha! Have a great day :o)